# SAML authentication using ADFS for IONIC mobile app?

Tags: ionic-framework, saml-2.0

I am looking for a way to put my own login page, create SAML assertion and send to our ADFS server as a SAML request from my IONIC app. Any help on how it could be done.

I got my app url registered as Relying Party on our ADFS using [ionic app custom url](http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/)

I am not allowed to share my ADFS server details so I can not use:
[auth0-ionic](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-ionic)

Is there any other way to use my own login page and send a SAML request for ADFS
authentication?

I did find one option, to manually generate SAML request xml as a string and send the request, not sure if there is a better way available.

Appreciate your help. Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks

Comment: Is your intention to act as service provider or identity provider?

Comment: Thanks for responding Suresh. My ionic mobile app will act as a service provider.

Comment: @Anil I am facing the same issue. How did you manually generate SAML Request XML ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I ended up sending a request to an IIS server, and the server then generated the SAML request